# Python Pulling the longest word from a file

Tags: python

Hope everyone is doing well. I need to write a program in Python that reads through a .txt file and finds the longest word. It would be simple but there are some restrictions.

You can't use the input function, split function or lists in any way.

I've been struggling with this all day. Anyone got any ideas or can at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: what if 2 words have the same length?

Comment: Make your own split function that splits words by spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `re` module as an alternative of using the `split` function:

```
import re

def longest_word(file_name="try.txt"):
    longest_word = ""
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
         for line in file.readlines():
             for word in re.findall(r'\S+', line):
                 if len(word ) > len(longest_word):
                     longest_word = word
    return longest_word, len(longest_word)

word, length = longest_word("test.txt")
```

Comment: He is not allowed to use `split()`